# Converting a single dynamic plot into dynamic plot with subplots in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have the code below, which works great with a single plot, but I'm trying to create a new plot with 1x2 subplots. The second plot will be identical to the first, just in another subplot.

```html
# This code works fine as a single plot
%matplotlib inline
import time
import pylab as pl
from IPython import display
for i in range(10):
    pl.clf()
    pl.plot(pl.randn(100))
    display.display(pl.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

I'm not familar with pylab, but the above plot runs so smoothly compared to the pyplot code I found on the nex, that I'm trying to figure out how to implement this code with subplots.

```
#can't implement it to a plot with subplots
%matplotlib inline
import time
import pylab as pl
from IPython import display
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, sharex = True, figsize = (10,5))
for i in range(10):
    pl.clf()
    ax1.plot(pl.randn(100),)
    ax2.plot(pl.randn(50))
    display.display(pl.show())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

However, no graph is being outputted with my attempt. 
I'm played around with this code, but I can't seem to make it work cleanly.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To visualize the plot with subplots, you should know the differences between `Figure` and `Axes` in matplotlib. Basically, axes belong to the figure, and you want to plot your data in the axes, but display the figure. Both `Figure` and `Axes` instances can be obtained with a single call to `pl.subplots(nrow, ncol)`. See if the code below does what you want:

```
%matplotlib inline
import time
import pylab as pl
from IPython import display
for i in range(10):
    pl.clf()
    f, ax = pl.subplots(1, 2)
    ax[0].plot(pl.randn(100))
    ax[1].plot(pl.randn(100))
    display.display(f)
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: From what I understand, the "Figure" is the entire box, and the "axes" are the subplots itself. I understand it on an intuitive sense but I'm still not getting the hang of the code.  I will test it out and reply.

Comment: Thanks it works. So the mistake I was making was, I was not displaying the  figure.  Your explanation clears a lot of things up. Thank you =)